# Unusual output of triple pointer

Tags: c, pointers

While I was working on a code to grasp the usage of pointers and moreover, assigning double and triple pointers to see what happens, I came up with this result . Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main (void) 
{

  struct entry 
  {
    int value ;
    struct entry *next ;
  } ;

  struct entry n1, n2, n3 ;

 struct entry* Ptr1 ;
 struct entry* *Ptr2 ;
 struct entry* **Ptr3 ;

 n1.value = 100 ;
 n2.value = 200 ;
 n3.value = 300 ;

 Ptr1 = &n1 ;      /* Ptr1 points to entry n1 */

 Ptr1 = &n3 ;      /* Ptr1 now points to n2 */

 Ptr2 = &Ptr1 ;    /* Ptr2 points to where pointer Ptr points, i.e the entry n3 */

 Ptr3 = &Ptr2 ;    /* Moreover, Ptr3 points to where pointer Ptr2 does. */


 printf("\n The value of where Ptr1 points is : %d,\n The address of Ptr1 is : %d \n" , *Ptr1, Ptr1) ;
 printf("\n The value of where Ptr2 points is : %d,\n The address of Ptr2 is : %d \n", **Ptr2, Ptr2) ;
 printf("\n The value of where Ptr3 points is : %d,\n The address of Ptr3 is : %d \n", ***Ptr3,Ptr3) ; 

 printf("\n") ;

 printf(" The value of where Ptr2 points is : %d ,\n The value of where Ptr3 points is : %d ", **Ptr2, ***Ptr3 ) ;      

  system("pause") ;

 }
```

Here is my output :

```
    The value of where Ptr1 points is : 300
    The address of Ptr1 is :-858993460

    The value of where Ptr2 points is : 300
    The address of Ptr2 is :-858993460

    The value of where Ptr3 points is : 300
    The address of Ptr3 is :-858993460
```

In the single line though, where I only print the values of where Ptr2 and Ptr3 point, I got this :

```
  The value of Ptr2 is : 300
  The value of Ptr3 is : -858993460
```

I don't get it. Isn't it supposed to print the same result in a single print? Am I missing something?

Thanks a priori.

Comment: well in your "output" part you have "the value of ptr2" and "the address of ptr2" repeated twice. you may want that looked at

Comment: Think about this: what is the type of `*Ptr1`, and what format specifier are you using to actually print that value? Mismatched format specifiers result in *undefined behavior*, which is a great source of funny and annoying bugs. Like this. (Also: to print pointers/addresses, you need the `%p` format specifier, not `%d`, especially if you're on a 64-bit system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second value you are sending to `printf` is wrong every single time. This is because you are passing the whole struct to `printf`, and not just the integer. I could go into excruciating detail about this (and I sorta do below), but just know that `printf` is a variadic function, and variadic functions are very finicky in C.

What is actually happening is that you are copying the whole entry struct onto the stack when you pass it in as the first parameter. For reference, the size of your struct is `8` bytes (well, for instructional purposes it is).

The variadic argument of a function (like `printf`) is treated as just a bunch of bytes on the stack. Therefore, when you ask for the first integer out of `printf` (with the `%d` specifier), it takes the first 4 bytes off the stack. These are the first 4 bytes of your struct, which just so happen to be the first member, your `value`.

When you ask for the next 4 bytes with another `%d`, the result is the value of the uninitialized pointer `next` in your struct. Some compilers, like Visual Studio's, like to initialize pointers with the value 0xCCCCCCCC, to show they haven't been set. In decimal, this is -858993460. **Every time you are calling `printf`, this uninitialized pointer is the second printed integer.** Because of the size of your struct if you were to print another integer in any of those `printf` statements, you'd get the actual address you wanted.

So for a solution, just print the value member of the struct:

```
printf("\n The value of where Ptr1 points is : %d,\n The address of Ptr1 is : %d \n" , Ptr1->value, Ptr1) ;
printf("\n The value of where Ptr2 points is : %d,\n The address of Ptr2 is : %d \n", *Ptr2->value, Ptr2) ;
printf("\n The value of where Ptr3 points is : %d,\n The address of Ptr3 is : %d \n", **Ptr3->value,Ptr3) ;
```

So your problem isn't actually with double or triple pointers, just with some weird functionality of C.

Keep in mind you need one less dereference operator `*` if you are using the `->` operator.

And be careful with what you actually pass into `printf`.